# Chrome on Mac displays time with (MST), yet Chrome on PC displays time with (Mountain Standard Time)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

I'm using the jQuery Weekly Calendar plugin (https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/). When I alert the startTime and endTime (which also go in a database), I get different results on Mac and Windows.

Chrome on Mac shows the time as:

**Sat Nov 26 2011 13:10:00 GMT-0700 (MST)**

Where as Chrome on Windows shows the time as:

**Sat Nov 26 2011 13:10:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)**

Any ideas why that would be happening? In the jQuery Weekly Calendar script, I was thinking maybe these lines need to be changed somehow:

```
$timestampsOfOptions.start[timeslotTimes[i].startFormatted] = startTime.getTime();
$timestampsOfOptions.end[timeslotTimes[i].endFormatted] = endTime.getTime();
```

But I'm not really sure to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime()` isn't what needs to be changed -- [it returns a numeric value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

The output you're looking at looks like the raw output from JavaScript's native [`Date.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) method, whose output is *not guaranteed* to be in any specific format. In particular, the names of time zones are often not the same from system to system -- if you need consistent output, you're probably out of luck.